# First app in android studio, R class

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I've install android studio for learning developing apps in Android. I've installed newest Java and android studio but in first generated Hello world project, I have many issues with `R` class. Android version for rendering is 5.1.1.

When I click on `activity_main.xml`, I don't have smartphone illustration for design. There is the following error:

```
NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views.
Fix compilation problems first.  The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout   at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)   at 
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:84)   at 
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:56)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: This is a common problem called the Layout Rendering problem.
Try changing the gradle build version to 1.2.3

Answer (score 1):

In the preview tab, just change the Preview version from "Automatically pick best" to "21" and it should work just fine.

Comment: when i switch to auto pick best always choose Android M preview and  create this issues:

This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio

and problem with R is already

Comment: @mathew92 the problem is quite clear: you need a newer version of android studio. to work with M preview, you need to change your update channel to "beta", because working with M isn't yet pushed to the main update channel. to switch to beta, go to Help > Check for Update... > Updates dialog, and change to "beta" or more recent builds.

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović its wrote me "You already have the latest version of Android Studio installed" .. i was download and install only yesterday

Comment: @mathew92 did you switch to beta channel?

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović yes, and next try again check for update and all is newest

Comment: It's just a problem with the rendering. Android studio is not yet up to date. Just downgrade the preview version and should be fine. Works for me.

Comment: @AniD can you tell me how please?

Comment: Check [this](http://i.imgur.com/ChJ6hTk.png) screenshot. Just downgrade it and it's done

Comment: @AniD Thanks, xml designer start works but R class still not found :/
http://ctrlv.cz/shots/2015/06/01/1Wr1.png

Comment: Import your packagename.R class in your activity. If your package is com.example.android, just import com.example.android.R

Comment: @AniD i tried this import but not found ... is also red

Answer (score 0):

Update your SDK Android or change version rendering on smaller
[image]

Comment: i try this ... project > open module settings and change compile sdk to android 5.0 and build tools version to 22.0.1 and after change extends ActionBarActivity to extends AppCompatActivity and errors are gone ... but new when run emulator app is not in him .. :/